# Как правильно написать загрузку файлов с учетом сети и диска?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность

Есть код, который просто использует `Parallel.ForEach` чтобы хоть как то распараллелить загрузки, выглядит как то так:

```
Parallel.ForEach(books)
-Parallel.ForEach(chapters)
--Download(page)
--Save(page)
```

Т.е. на каждый верхнеуровневый элемент может параллельно быть запущено любое число скачиваний, на узком канале всё проседает и часто можно получить таймаут.
Ещё хуже, когда одновременно начатые загрузки заканчиваются тоже примерно в одно время и пытаются писать на диск параллельно.

Сейчас у меня основной вопрос - а будет ли лучше, если сделать что-то вида:

```
var tasks = books
.SelectMany(b => b.Chapters)
.SelectMany(c => c.Pages)
.Select(p => Task.Run(() => p.Download(); p.Save())
tasks.WaitAll();
```

В каком случае оптимальнее будет нагрузка на сеть и диск? Сеть пока критичнее, ибо по таймауту приходится повторять операцию загрузки.

UPDATE: сделал вариант через таски - на 200 страниц спокойно выходит до 30 загрузок одновременно. При этом больше половины в состоянии Blocking, на завершении загрузки. Автоматических ограничений на количество активных тасок всё таки нет или что? Как бы это оптимальнее сделать?

UPDATE2: Код загрузки:

```
internal static ImageFile DownloadFile(Uri uri)
{
  byte[] result;
  WebResponse response;
  var file = new ImageFile();
  var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

  try
  {
    response = request.GetResponse();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
      result = ms.ToArray();
    }
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    Log.Exception(ex, string.Format("Загрузка {0} не завершена.", uri));
    return file;
  }
  if (response.ContentLength == result.LongLength)
    file.Body = result;
  return file;
}
```

Висят заблокированные таски, плюс парочка работающих снизу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У заблокированных вот такой стек:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно сделать буфер и заполнять его, а он в один поток будет сбрасывать содержимое на диск. Заодно можно проверять нагруженность диска, как это любит делать uTorrent, а также дать немного ума буферу и реордерить блоки чтобы меньше головка прыгала по диску. А с сетью только ограничивать количество одновременных загрузок или же писать свой даунлоадер, который будет балансировать входящие потоки данных (хотя я не знаю возможно ли это вообще). Ограничение конечно есть - таскпул, да и незачем качать из сети CPU-bound потоками

Comment: @vitidev балансировщик я в целом представляю, пока вроде не нужен. Таски почему не завершаются, я не понимаю. Для медленного сайта только что умудрился получить цифры вида на 1500 страниц - 1200 одновременно запущенных тасок. Почему стартуют новые, не завершив существующие? При этом нарастание постепенное, не в один момент все 1.5 стартанули, но копились blocked tasks.

Comment: мне сложно судить что там у вас происходит, ведь по моему знанию Parallel.ForEach ориентируется на количество ядер (а Download() вроде бы не асихронный), а Select упрется в размер таскпула, который по дефолту равен 20 и таким образом 1200 запущенных тасок не получить (запланированных может быть)

Comment: @vitidev добавил код загрузки, сомневаюсь правда, что станет понятнее.

Comment: Попытался создать отдельно проект, который бы так грузил файлы - с ним всё в порядке, 4 активных таски, остальные "запланированы". Очень интересно, как я смог у себя отломать такое ожидаемое поведение тасок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, суть в следующем.

Загрузка файлов и запись на диск, запущенные асинхронно, "отпускают" CPU-тред, а значит из таскпула может быть запущена очередная таска.

Учитывая, что у меня там таски однотипные, загрузка любого числа ссылок запускается практически одновременно, а потом ждут свободного треда, чтобы записать полученные байты. Только реальная сеть на такие кейсы не расчитана (как и жесткий диск), а значит в худшем случае запросы поделят канал пользователя на совсем мизерные пропускные скорости и не дадут скачать большую часть.

Видимо, придётся рулить этим вручную, ограничивая максимальное число сетевых таскок (надо ещё придумать или найти способ правильно расчитать ограничение) и тасок, работающих с жестким диском (тут мне просто не понятно, есть ли смысл в больше чем одной асинхронной записи на диск).

UPD: решил семафором, минимум кода, максимум пользы:

```
 protected static SemaphoreSlim Throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(25);
```

ну и абстрактно скачивание вышло как то так:

```
 await Throttler.WaitAsync(); 
 var file = await ImageFile.DownloadFile(this.ImageLink); 
 Throttler.Release();
```

UPD2: на деле, очень тяжело найти универсальную цифру, которая бы работала при любой ширине канала. 200 работало стабильно, но так же стабильно оказалось работает в 25-30. Поэтому в итоге уменьшил до 25, легче прерывать процесс, если что случится.

Comment: На самом деле, сетевой стек способен держать очень большое число одновременных загрузок - протокол TCP все предусматривает. Проблемы начинаются либо на стороне дешевых роутеров, которые пытаются делать NAT для всех этих потоков - либо на стороне сервера, который может решить что соединение слишком долго тянется и отрубить его. А, и еще в винде число полуоткрытых соединений ограничено (эта информация могла устареть).

Comment: Подобные вещи (количество одновременных загрузок) надо выносить в настройки.

Comment: Кстати, смысл асинхронно записывать на диск - есть. Дисковая подсистема переупорядочивает запросы к диску в зависимости от физического расположения файлов - и чем больше запросов активно, тем эффективнее они будут обработаны.

Comment: @PavelMayorov за информацию по диску - спасибо. А вот настройки количества одновременных загрузок - очень спорная вещь. На сервере каком - я бы ещё согласился, но у меня клиентское приложение, когда на пользователя надо вывалить минимум настроек, особенно таких сложных.

Comment: Это необходимость. Максимальное количество сильно зависит от сервера, слабее - от канала. Вот понадобится загрузить картинки с сервера, где админы ввели правило "больше двух загрузок длительное время - бан по IP", и что пользователь будет делать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov логично, надо подумать. Тут же главное чтобы пользователь не поставил большую цифру в надежде скачивать быстрее. Далеко не всегда цифры ведут себя очевидно. Скорее уж тогда для пользователя перечисление из 1-2-4-много. И то не факт, что поможет.